# Getting started with pure ECS

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get started with pure ECS in Unity 2018.3.6f1, I am starting simple by just having a sphere prefab move in one direction, but I am getting no prefabs created it seems.

I have a empty game object prefab with a RenderMesh that has a Sphere mesh and a simple material, and I have this script attached to the prefab also:

```
using System;
using Unity.Entities;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public struct Position : IComponentData
{
    public Vector3 Value;
}

public class BoidPositionComponent : ComponentDataProxy<Position> { }
```

Then I have this SteeringSystem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Transforms;
using UnityEngine;

public class SteeringSystem : JobComponentSystem
{
    [BurstCompile]
    struct SteeringJob : IJobProcessComponentData<Position>
    {
        public float deltaTime;

        public void Execute(ref Position position)
        {
            Vector3 value = position.Value;
            value = new Vector3(value.x + deltaTime + 1.0f, value.y, value.z);
            position.Value = value;
        }
    }

    protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps)
    {
        SteeringJob steeringJob = new SteeringJob
        {
            deltaTime = Time.deltaTime
        };
        JobHandle jobHandle = steeringJob.Schedule(this, inputDeps);
        return jobHandle;
    }
}
```

And lastly I have a empty game object in my scene with this script on:

```
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Rendering;
using Unity.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ECSWorld : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boidPrefab;

    private static EntityManager entityManager;
    private static RenderMesh renderMesh;
    private static EntityArchetype entityArchetype;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        entityManager = World.Active.GetOrCreateManager<EntityManager>();
        entityArchetype = entityManager.CreateArchetype(typeof(Position));
        AddBoids();
    }

    void AddBoids()
    {
        int amount = 200;
        NativeArray<Entity> entities = new NativeArray<Entity>(amount, Allocator.Temp);
        entityManager.Instantiate(boidPrefab, entities);
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            // Do stuff, like setting data...
            entityManager.SetComponentData(entities[i], new Position { Value = Vector3.zero });
        }
        entities.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But I am not seeing anything when I run the game. Should it not instanciate 200 og my prefab and have them move on the screen? What am I missing here?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a renderer that actually renders your boids. You have created a custom `Position` component, but there is no system that actually does rendering based on it. So all you do is create entities and modify your `Position` component in memory (you should see this in the entity debugger) but since you have no renderer, you will not see anything on screen.

For now I would suggest [using the "Hybrid Renderer" package](https://www.effectiveunity.com/ecs/03-preparing-your-project/) that is available in the package manager. It uses its own set of components:

- `Translation` for the position in 3D space
- `Scale` for the scale in world space
- `Rotation` for the rotation in world space
- `RenderMesh`for the mesh to be renderer (you are already using this)

With the current ECS version you can actually just [convert a classic game object into an entity](https://www.effectiveunity.com/ecs/04-a-first-example/#making-it-run) by adding a "Convert To Entity" Monobehaviour to it. This makes editor-integration a lot easier as you don't need all those proxy components. The auto-conversion process will automatically add the `Translation`, `Scale`, `Rotation` and `RenderMesh` components to your ECS entity.